# How to prevent top and bottom bar blocking my main content in a view controller (iOS)

Tags: ios

one of the screens in my app displays a full screen UIImageView that you can zoom in and out. However the problem is navigation bar and bottom bar in that screen blocks the UIImageView tops and bottoms. How can I make sure bars don't block the content?

[image]

Comment: Check out `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide`. Answer depends on how you create view, but that two UIViewController properties are the answer.

Comment: I am actually using a library called MWPhotoBrowser to create the view. Createing the view controller like this: let mygalleryVC = MyGalleryVC(rootViewController: browser)

Answer (score 0):

If the view you've shown above is the one entirely created in the MWPhotoBrowser library then you'll have to rely on that library to take care of the photo sizing. The only options I see in their code that might help are:

```
browser.zoomPhotosToFill = YES; // Images that almost fill the screen will be initially zoomed to fill (defaults to YES)
browser.alwaysShowControls = NO; // Allows to control whether the bars and controls are always visible or whether they fade away to show the photo full (defaults to NO)
```

You might play with those settings to see if they help adjust your view.

Comment: I am afraid these settings do nothing. I was hoping I could override some of the settings in the navigation controller to fix the issue. I embed the photo browser in a custom navigation controller.

Comment: Does your custom nav controller have a nav bar or are you hiding your nav bar so you can see the photo browser nav bar?

Answer (score 0):

in short words: you may change layer's opacity property, 0 means 100% hide, 1 means 100% show

when your image view shows on screen, change opacity of both navigationBar and tabBar to 0, and change these opacity values to 1 if not. you may add gesture recognizer to the image view to change opacity.

code demo for Swift 3 & iOS 10

```
class DetailNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        let detailController = CustomDetailViewController()
        viewControllers = [detailController]
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(showOrHideBarView)))

    }

    func showOrHideBarView() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.navigationBar.layer.opacity = self.navigationBar.layer.opacity == 1 ? 0: 1
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.opacity = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.opacity == 1 ? 0: 1
        }
    }
}

class CustomDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupViews()
    }

    func setupViews() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```